# How set system assigned identity for default_nod_pool vmss in aks by terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

I wanted to get secrets from keyvault in aks. For that I need to get object id of vmss. I am using identity block in aks module but it's not working for vmss.

How do I set system assigned identity for node_pool vmss?

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "intellidoc_aks" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_name
  location            = var.location
  name                = var.cluster_name
  dns_prefix          = var.dns_prefix

  default_node_pool {
    name = "workernode"
    # vm_size         = "Standard_D8as_v5"
    vm_size         = "Standard_DS2_v2"
    node_count      = var.agent_count
    vnet_subnet_id  = var.aks_subnet_id
    os_disk_size_gb = 30
    max_pods        = 100
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    min_count           = 1
    max_count           = 3

  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "xyz"
    ssh_key {
      key_data = var.ssh_key
    }
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"

    dns_service_ip = "10.2.0.10"

    service_cidr = "10.2.0.0/16"

    network_policy = "azure"

    load_balancer_sku = "standard"
  }

  private_cluster_enabled = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an access policy like this:

```
# Give KV secret read permissions to the Managed Identity of AKS for CSI driver access
resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "aks_msi" {
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.foo.id

  tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kubelet_identity.0.object_id

  secret_permissions = [
    "Get", "List"
  ]
}
```

or if you are using RBAC instead (which I would recommend)

```
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "foo" {
  scope                = azurerm_key_vault.foo.id
  role_definition_name = "Key Vault Secrets User"
  principal_id         = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.foo.kubelet_identity.0.object_id
}
```